# Dart Error: An equality expression can't be an operand of another equality expression

Tags: dart

I can't do this in Dart?

`if (limit != null | pageby != null) { .. }` as I get this error

`An equality expression can't be an operand of another equality expression`

So how do I do an `if (this or that) { .. }` in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *logical OR* is `||`. So you should use:

```
if (limit != null || pageby != null) { .. }
```